# How to set array property value in code using Carina Test Framework for API tests?

Tags: api, testing, automation, frameworks

I have the following request json body:

```
{
...
"attachmentIds": "${attachments}"
...
}
```

I have a properties file that includes the declaration of the corresponding placeholder

I want to set array of strings in code instead of "attachments" placeholder, but `getProperties().setProperty()` expects only string value.

How can I achieve it other way or is it possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can transform your array into the String in java code. And then pass this String as property value.

Another option, you can pass String array from code and then parse it in your json template.
For example:

```
String[] arr = { "1", "2", "3" };
apiMethod.addProperty("attachments", arr);
```

And then in your json:

```
{
"attachmentIds": [<#list attachments as val>"${val}"<#if val?has_next>,</#if></#list>]
}
```

Check freemarker documentation to get more details:
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html

Also please note that some of freemarker functions (including `has_next`) are available only in newest versions of library. So make sure to add into your dependencies list. Carina is now in process of migrating to latest freemarker version.